# How do I update my own application in the software center?

Tags: software-center, application-development

Some applications use web services to provide services to users (especially Unity lenses). Things with APIs that might change, or things that might be updated. So what happens when someone submits a Reddit Lens and then a week later it breaks and it needs to be updated?

Is there a process where I as an application author can update my application in the software center independent of the Ubuntu release cycle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely. If you are an app author who has submitted an application to the Software Centre through the [My Apps](http://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com) web interface on the [Ubuntu App Developer Site](http://developer.ubuntu.com/), you can distribute updates following this easy process:

- [Updating your app in the Software Centre](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/updating-your-app/)

Answer (score -1):

Probably try to update in `Github`, Its will support all Linux.

Not specially Ubuntu. 
 -

1. You will get more response and 
      2.you will reduce your app bug also. so more advantages.